# python is asking of existing argument in test

Tags: python, django, signals

I try to test signals. I have signal item in app.signals.py

```
from django.dispatch import Signal 
task_completed = Signal(providing_args=['balance'])
```

Func is in user.views and it update balance according to task cost

```
from django.contrib.messages import success
from users.models import User
from django.db.models import F
from freelance.signals import task_completed


def update_balance(cls, balance):
    User.objects.select_for_update().filter(user_type=User.CUSTOMER).update(
        balance=F('balance') - balance
    )
    User.objects.select_for_update().filter(user_type=User.EXECUTER).update(
        balance=F('balance') + balance
    )
    if success:
        task_completed.send_robust(
            sender=cls,
            balance=balance,
        )
```

func is called in task.models after task creation

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Task)
def task_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.assignee.update_balance(instance.money)
```

And finally test that I want to make for all this things

```
class TestCharge(TestCase):
    def test_should_send_signal_when_charge_succeeds(self):
        self.signal_was_called = False
        self.total = None

        def handler(sender, balance, **kwargs):
            self.signal_was_called = True
            self.total = balance

        task_completed.connect(handler)

        update_balance(100)

        self.assertTrue(self.signal_was_called)
        self.assertEqual(self.total, 100)

        task_completed.disconnect(handler)
```

But it gives mistake like

```
TypeError: update_balance() missing 1 required positional argument: 'balance'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the error, you are not passing required arguments inside **update_balance()**.
The error is in this line :

```
update_balance(100)
```

But according to your function definition:

```
def update_balance(cls, balance):
```

**update_balance** takes two arguments, so you need to update your code like this :

```
class TestCharge(TestCase):
    def test_should_send_signal_when_charge_succeeds(self):
        self.signal_was_called = False
        self.total = None

        def handler(sender, balance, **kwargs):
            self.signal_was_called = True
            self.total = balance

        task_completed.connect(handler)

        update_balance("First value here",100)

        self.assertTrue(self.signal_was_called)
        self.assertEqual(self.total, 100)

        task_completed.disconnect(handler)
```